# How is a call to static method resolved in java?

Tags: java, static

If static methods are resolved at compile time how is an object instance able to call a static method?

```
class StaticCall
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String arr[]={"Class StaticCall","calls static method of class MyMainClass"};

        MyMainClass h=new MyMainClass();
        h.main(arr);         //How is an instance able to call a static method?
        System.out.println("this is StaticCall main");  
    }   

}


class MyMainClass 
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(args[0]+" "+ args[1]);
    }
}
```

After running the StaticCall class the output is

Class StaticCall calls static method of class MyMainClass

this is StaticCall main

As static fields and methods belong to the Class object how is an instance able to call a static method?
Also when is the Class object created,Is it on first access to any of it's fields or methods?

Comment: The compiler knows the type.

Comment: @Nambari Because the compiler knows the type.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> How is an instance able to call a static method?

It doesn't. Try this instead

```
MyMainClass h = null;
h.main(arr);
```

and you will see that the instance is ignored as this is exactly the same as

```
MyMainClass.main(arr);
```

---

To extend your example ... if you have

```
class AnotherMainClass extends MyMainClass 
{
}
```

then all the following call the same method.

```
AnotherMainClass amc = null;
amc.main(args);

((AnotherMainClass) null).main(args);

AnotherMainClass.main(args);

MyMainClass mmc = null;
mmc.main(args);

((MyMainClass) null).main(args);

MyMainClass.main(args);
```

Comment: +1 for h=null; example. May be you could add some more description, it is using Type ?

Comment: I think it's using the compile time type of h which happens to be MyMainClass

Answer (score 4):

```
 h.main(arr);         //How is an instance able to call a static method?
```

This is just a shortcut for `MyMainClass.main(arr)`, i.e. the static type of `h`. The usage is often frowned upon and most IDEs will recommend you use the type instead of instance.

Since this occurs at compile time, `h` can be null

Answer (score 1):

you can call static method by `classname.staticMethod` and even `instance.staticMethod`, `instance.staticMethod` internally call `classname.staticMethod`.